# Mostrar nested en show del modelo padre

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo 2 modelos tengo un padre y otro hijo, puedo crear sin problemas el formulario hijo dentro del padre.

```
<h3>Agregar Programa</h3>
<%= link_to_add_association 'Agregar', f, :lists, 
  'data-association-insertion-node' => "#lists ol",
  'data-association-insertion-method' => "append",
  :wrap_object => Proc.new {|list| list}, class: 'btn btn-primary'  %>

<hr/>
<fieldset id="lists">
  <ol>
    <%= f.fields_for :lists do |list| %>
      <%= render partial: "list_fields", locals: { f: list} %>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
</fieldset>
```

pero ahora, como puedo hacer que en el `show.html.erb` del padre, se muestre también lo que se introdujo en el hijo?

No sé si me explico.

Comment: ¿Y que es lo que tienes hecho actualmente en tu show? Podrías agregarlo también a tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias maneras de hacerlo. la primeria seria cargar una variable global desde la accion de tu controlador esta me imagino seria el show entonces seria algo asi.

```
def show
  @padre = Padre.find(params[id])
  # Este metodo hijos que escribo seria el nombre de tu relacion has_many
  # que tengas en tu modelo.
  @hijos = @padre.hijos
end

# Luego en tu show.html.erb tendrias que recorrer tu variable
@hijos.each do |hijo|
  # aqui escribirias todo el html para renderizar tus hijos
  <p><%= hijo.nombre %></p>
end
```

La otra forma seria que con tu variable global padre desde el controlador en la accion show llames a tu relacion desde la vista. ejemplo

```
def show
  # solo retornarias el padre en la accion
  @padre = Padre.find(params[id])
end


# y en tu vista show.html.erb tendrias que llamar a tu relacion con la 
# variable padre
# el metodo hijos seria el nombre de tu relacion has_many que tengas en tu modelo.
@padre.hijos.each do |hijo|
  # aqui escribirias todo el html para renderizar tus hijos
  <p><%= hijo.nombre %></p>
end
```

Espero te ayude.